# Excel crashes on large array lookups

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some firewall logs I am looking through and I want to arrange them so that excel shows me the first and last timestamp (two separate columns) for each IP.
I have a table with five columns:

- ColumnA: Unique IP addresses (count:1,275)
- ColumnB:Where I would like the first accessed times to be
- ColumnC:Where I would like the last accessed times to be
- ColumnD: Non uniqued IP addresses (count:300,001)
- ColumnE: Non uniqued timestamps aligned with column 4 (count:300,001)

My formula seems to work fine on smaller data sets but excel crashes when I try to do this, understandably so since it is a 400k line table. Is there a way to make this less CPU intensive so that Excel completes this? Is there a better way to be doing this? Here is the current formula I am using:

`=MIN(IF(A1=D1:D400001,E1:E400001))`

ctrl+shift+enter

Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be a formula? Can you just pivot the data? Put the IP Addresses on rows and the timestamps on values (Summarize value field by Minimum).

Comment: Why are you looking at 100,000 blank rows? Your formula says `D1:D400001` but your narrative states *'count:300,001'* for the same range.

Comment: If you have removed all conditional formatting, custom formatting, etc. and are left with raw data then you shouldn't have a problem. Your array formula ran through 1275 unique IPs over a true 400K non-blank values in 54.04 seconds. I tested it against an [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) equivalent which ran slower at 66.85 seconds. Not lightning quick but perfectly acceptable given the amount of data on an older laptop.

Comment: @rwilson I tried the pivot with the same data as in my answer and I have to admit that it is even quicker than the sort and easier ;-)

Comment: The only advantage of my sort/match/index might be if you want to report on the whole list of 1,275 IP addresses and display blanks for unused ones - the pivot only shows ones which are actually used in the list of 300,000. But I'm guessing that they might all be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with this many rows of data, your best bet is to create a pivot table (See Table Below). Pivot tables are extremely fast and are perfect for situations just like this.

[image]

**1.** Place the IP Addresses (Non Unique IP Addresses Column) on "ROWS".

**2.** Drag TimeStamps (Non Unique Timestamps column) on "VALUES". This will default to SUM or COUNT, but using the field settings you can change this to MIN.

**3** Once again drag TimeStamps on "VALUES" and this time change the field settings to MAX.

This table will practically give you the same results you would get from using your MINIF and MAXIF formulas.

As noted by Tom Sharpe, the pivot table will only list out the IP addresses that are found in the Non Unique IP Addresses column which may or may not include all 1,275 unique IP addresses. To get around this (if necessary), you could just create a formula using the pivot table itself as the lookup table and bring the values back over to the original spreadsheet.

Comment: Pivot tables are extraordinarily powerful. Thank you sir, this did it!

Answer (score 0):

How about this old-school approach? My formulae start in row 2 because I prefer column headings to do a sort:-

(1) Sort on col D then E

(2) Use MATCH(,,0) to get the first date for each IP number & INDEX in B2:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E$2:E$300000,MATCH(A2,D$2:D$300000,0)),"")
```

(3) Use MATCH(,,1) to get the last date for each IP number & INDEX in C2:-

```
=IF(B2="","",INDEX(E$2:E$300000,MATCH(A2,D$2:D$300000,1)))
```

If the formula in B2 doesn't find a match because the IP address in A2 hasn't been used, then display a blank in both B2 and C2.

I ran it on some simulated data on a run-of-the-mill PC and it took about 5 seconds to sort, and a similar time to update the formulae.

Worth considering for larger amounts of data because sort time goes up as nlog(n), not n<sup>2</sup>.

It's tagged as Excel, but it's also something that would be handled easily by any SQL database.